# Can someone please explain how does this works x[0][0][0] fine where x is string , say x = "This is text file" in python?

Tags: python

Can someone please explain how does this works `x[0][0][0]` fine where `x` is string , say

```
x = "This is text file"
```

in python?

Comment: What is `x[0]`? The string `'T'`. What is `[0]` of the string `'T'`…? The string `'T'`…

Comment: `x[0]` is `"T"`. `"T"[0]` is also `"T"`. `[0]` gives you the first character of a string, which is represented as a string of length 1.

Comment: Have you tried running it step by step?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't understand a complex expression, break it down into its components and evaluate it step by step.

```
result = x[a][b][c]
```

is equivalent to:

```
temp1 = x[a]
temp2 = temp1[b]
result = temp2[c]
```

In the case of `x[0][0][0]`:

`temp1` is the first character of `x`, which is `"T"`.

`temp2` is the first character of `temp1`, which is `"T"`.

`result` is the first character of `temp2`, which is `"T"`.

You can have as many `[0]` as you want because Python doesn't have separate character and string data types. When you subscript a string you get another string of length 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are slicing the text. First you take the 0th element, which is 'T'. From this string you again take the 0th element, which is again 'T'. And of course the final [0] gives again 'T'.